# How to use JsonReader work with URL and relationship between JsonObject and JsonArray

Tags: java, json

I am developing a java program which can retrieve certain data in my JSON data structure from web URL.

Here is my Json data:

```
{  
   "data_id":"a71a3c2588c6472bb4daea41a0b58835",
   "file_info":{  
      "display_name":"",
      "file_size":242,
      "file_type":"Not available",
      "file_type_description":"Not available",
      "md5":"aa69ba384f22d0dc0551ace2fbb9ad55",
      "sha1":"09ceb54e65df3d3086b222e8643acffe451a6e8a",
      "sha256":"dcb46d6ae2a187f789c12f19c44bbe4b9a43bd200a3b306d5e9c1fcf811dc430",
      "upload_timestamp":"2016-11-18T09:09:08.390Z"
   },
   "process_info":{  
      "blocked_reason":"",
      "file_type_skipped_scan":false,
      "post_processing":{  
         "actions_failed":"",
         "actions_ran":"",
         "converted_destination":"",
         "converted_to":"",
         "copy_move_destination":""
      },
      "profile":"File scan",
      "progress_percentage":100,
      "result":"Allowed",
      "user_agent":""
   },
   "scan_results":{  
      "data_id":"a71a3c2588c6472bb4daea41a0b58835",
      "progress_percentage":100,
      "scan_all_result_a":"No Threat Detected",
      "scan_all_result_i":0,
      "scan_details":{  
         "Ahnlab":{  
            "def_time":"2016-11-08T15:00:00.000Z",
            "location":"local",
            "scan_result_i":0,
            "scan_time":1,
            "threat_found":""
         },
         "Avira":{  
            "def_time":"2016-11-08T00:00:00.000Z",
            "location":"local",
            "scan_result_i":0,
            "scan_time":133,
            "threat_found":""
         },
         "ClamAV":{  
            "def_time":"2016-11-08T10:28:00.000Z",
            "location":"local",
            "scan_result_i":0,
            "scan_time":94,
            "threat_found":""
         },
         "ESET":{  
            "def_time":"2016-11-08T00:00:00.000Z",
            "location":"local",
            "scan_result_i":0,
            "scan_time":38,
            "threat_found":""
         }
      },
      "start_time":"2016-11-18T09:09:08.405Z",
      "total_avs":4,
      "total_time":250
   },
   "vulnerability_info":{  

   }
}
```

But the only data, I want is `scan_all_result_i` which belong to `scan_results` array but I am encountering some problem on it.Ii searched some information in Oracle website and it's showing that my code might be correct([reference 1](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonReaderFactory.html) and [reference 2](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/json-1973242.html))

The error still show up for the portion. How I handle the JSON data using `JsonReader`, `JSONObject` and `JSONArray`. Anyone here can guide me on how to the Json data processing? I've been figuring out this for few day and haven't any idea on it now.

Here is my java source

```
public class FetchResult {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, JSONException {
       URL theUrl = new URL ("http://192.168.0.25:8008/file/a71a3c2588c6472bb4daea41a0b58835");
       HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) theUrl.openConnection();
       con.setRequestMethod("GET");
       int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
       if(responseCode == 200)
       {
           try
           {
              InputStream is = theUrl.openStream();
              JsonReader read = JsonReader.createReader(is);
              JSONObject obj = read.readObject();
              JSONArray result = obj.getJSONArray("scan_results");
              For(JSONObject result : result.getValueAs(JSON.Object.class))
              {
                  System.out.print(result.getString("scan_all_result_i"));
              }
        //    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject (); 
        //    obj.getJsonObject("scan_results");
        //    System.out.println(obj.toString());
           }
           catch(MalformedURLException e)
           {
               System.out.print("your problem here ...1");
           }
       }
       else
       {
           System.out.print("Can't Connect");
       }
    }
```

The error message, I got in my eclipse compiler

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
>           The method createReader(InputStream) is undefined for the type JsonReader
>           Type mismatch: cannot convert from JsonObject to JSONObject
>           Syntax error on token "JSONObject", ? expected after this token
>           JSONObject cannot be resolved to a variable
>           The method getValueAs(Class) is undefined for the type JSONArray
>           JSON cannot be resolved to a type
>           Syntax error, insert ";" to complete Statement
>           The method getString(int) in the type JSONArray is not applicable for the arguments (String)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At for loop, it should be

```
 for (Object obj : result) {
      JSONObject jsonObj = (JSONObject) obj;
      System.out.print(jsonObj.getString("scan_all_result_i"));
     }
```

Comment: so i can't exclude the JSONArray as well ? just use the JSONObject ?